# Pouchdb query not filtering KEY when turning on the device

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-promise, pouchdb

Hello I have this pouchdb query:

```
function(test, key){
        var temp = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
        var day = [];

        $q.when(cigdb.query('learnIndex/by_data_type',{key: key, include_docs : true})).then(function(res){
                $q.all(res.rows.map(function(row){
                    console.log(row.doc);
                    day.push(row.doc.day);
                    return temp[row.doc.hour]++;
            }));
        }).then(function(te){
            day = day.unique();
            console.log(day);
            test.splice(0,24);
            for(var i = 0; i<24; i++){
                if(day.length > 0){
                    test.push(temp[i]/day.length);
                }else{                    
                    test.push(temp[i]);
                }
            }
            console.log(test);
            return test;
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err); 
        }); 
    },
```

which works well on the browser but when debugging it on the device (android)
it jumps part of the code.

On the device it executes until the 
`$q.all(...)` then it ignores completely the block :

```
 console.log(row.doc);
 day.push(row.doc.day);
 return temp[row.doc.hour]++;
```

And keeps going executing the promise `.then(function(te)` as nothing was wrong

obs: my first work with js angular and ionic not really familiar with that

Thanks for any help

edit:
I already did try whith `Promise.all(...)`
and putting a return before `$q.all(...) and Promise.all(...)`

and on all of then did work on the browser but on the device the problem was the same.

edit2 : so after diging a bit if i send on `console.log(res)` just before `$q.all()` it returns :

```
Object {total_rows: 32, offset: 0, rows: Array[0]}
offset: 0
rows:    Array[0]
total_rows: 32
__proto__: Object
```

while on the browser i have:

```
Object {total_rows: 11, offset: 0, rows: Array[10]}
offset: 0
rows: Array[10]
total_rows: 11
__proto__: Object
```

for some reason pouchdb is not populating the `row`

edit3:

changing the code:

```
q.when(cigdb.query('learnIndex/by_data_type',{key: key, include_docs : true})).then(function(res){
                $q.all(res.rows.map(function(row){
                    day.push(row.doc.day);
                    return temp[row.doc.hour]++;
            }));
```

for :

```
$q.when(cigdb.query('learnIndex/by_data_type',{include_docs : true})).then(function(res){
                return $q.all(res.rows.map(function(row){
                    if(row.doc.data_type === key){
                    day.push(row.doc.day);
                    return temp[row.doc.hour]++;
                    }
                }));
```

makes it work but now i dont get why the `key` is not filtering as supposed on de device 
what makes the query useless as i could use a simple `alldocs` if i have to implement the filtering any way.

Comment: If that block is jumped, then it probably means that `res.rows` is empty. Did you check its `.lenght`?

Comment: Yes, you should definitely place a `return` in front of that `$q.all`. However, I wonder why you are using `$q.all` at all; `temp` does not seem to contain any promises? Also, what are you `map`ping to? You don't seem to care for the result at all. Use a simply synchronous loop, and put it into the same `then` callback as `day.unique()`. No promise chaining is needed here.

Comment: bergi  i did check the obeject `res.rows` and it has data  and on question about on why the `$q.all()` the problem is if i do a symple synchronous loop the error is that res.rows return a `undefined` and this causes problems even in the browser

Comment: `$q.all` is called *after* `res.rows` gives `undefined`, it can't be used to solve problems with that. But if `res.rows` has no data, your callback obviously won't be executed either. You should receive an error, though.

Comment: bergi you are right the query is not returning anything i did some test and if i remove the `key` it works but then is no use do a query and it keeps returning all as i cant filter with the `key` is the same as using `alldocs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you need a `return` before the `$q.all()`. You might want to read this article on promises to catch up on common anti-patterns: [We have a problem with promises](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html).

As for the `key` issue, it depends on what your `map` function for `by_data_type` is doing. Whatever is the first argument to `emit()`, that's your key. If you need to debug, then you can omit the `key` parameter and check the `rows` object on the result. Each row will contain a `key` object so you can see what the key is.

You may also want to check out [pouchdb-find](http://nolanlawson.github.io/pouchdb-find/). It's a lot easier, especially if your map function is pretty straightforward.

Comment: nlawson i did add the return statement.
but my problem is that when i run the program on a android device i dont get any `key` but on the browser it runs propely

Comment: What version of Android is it? Which browsers have you tested? Are you using Cordova/SQLite Plugin/etc.?

Comment: In testing on android 5.1.1 and im using pouchdb with websql and i have tested on chrome

Comment: Hm, hard to say, then. PouchDB fully supports that platform. Maybe try asking in the #pouchdb IRC channel or the mailing list for help? Usually people are very responsive there and can give you guidance on your code. See the "discuss" links at the bottom of http://pouchdb.com

Comment: nlawson thanks for the tip pouchdb-find solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using the sqlite-legacy plugin and solved it using the `{ androidDatabaseImplementation: 2 }` flag when instantiating/creating the database.